# Avoiding orphan instances when defining instances with template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I want to define a Haskell module that exports a class `C` and instances of `C` for various types. Because I want to define a lot of instances, that can be defined automatically following a given scheme, I defined a helper TH function to define the instance somewhat like this:

```
module Foo (C) where

class C a

defineCInstance :: TypeQ -> DecsQ
defineCInstance t =
  [d|
    instance C $t
    |]

defineCInstance [t| () |]
defineCInstance [t| Char |]
defineCInstance [t| Int |]
```

However, the example above doesn't compile, because due to stage restrictions, it is not allowed to use `defineCInstance` in a splice in the same module it is defined in. This can be fixed by moving `defineCInstance` into a new module (let's call it `Foo.Internal`) and importing it in `Foo`. However when I just move `defineCInstance` into another module it won't have `C` in scope and I currently see two ways to work around this.

## Solution 1, Move `C` into `Foo.Internal` as well

If I move both `defineCInstance` and `C` into `Foo.Internal` `defineCInstance` can easily refer to `C` and I can splice `defineCInstance` in `Foo` without problems. However, the instance defined in `Foo` will not be defined in the same module as `C` anymore and thus become orphan instances. I would like to avoid this, because then I would have to silence the warning for orphans, which is AFAIK only possible for the whole file and might silence the warning for other unintended orphan instances in the same file. I also noticed that haddock then lists all the instances as orphan instances in the documentation, which I would like to avoid as well.

## Solution 2, Do not let `defineCInstance` refer to `C` directly.

Instead of referring to `instance C` inside `defineCInstance` I could use something like `instance $(conT $ mkName "C")` instead. However this hides the dependency between `C` and `defineCInstance` from the compiler, which makes errors more likely. For example, if I rename `C`, but forget to change the name in `defineCInstance` the compiler will still happily compile `defineCInstance`. Even worse, it relies on the correct `C` being in scope at the splice site of `defineCInstance`. If the user has the wrong `C` in scope, the generated code will be completely nonsensical.

Is there some way to define `C`, `defineCInstance` and the instances for `C` in a way, which still allows to refer to `C` directly from `defineCInstance` **and** avoids defining orphan instances?

Answer (score 2):

1. Define an internal `defineCInstance_` which takes the `Name` of `C` as a parameter;
2. In the external `Foo` module containing the class, use `defineCInstance_ ''Foo.C` for the standard instances;
3. Export `defineCInstance = defineCInstance_ ''Foo.C`, preventing users from using the wrong name.

In step 2 you can put all the relevant types in a list and traverse it all at once, so you only have to refer to the `''Foo.C` name twice: once in the splice, once in the exported `defineCInstance`.